# In Ubuntu 13.10.....Screen showing Black ,after login credentials...please reply

Tags: 13.10, login, screen

I am getting black screen and a moving cursor just after login page(after entering username and password).I had re-started several times but no use,please assist me.
Thanking you in advance.

please reply

Answer (score 0):

In the login screen press ctrl+alt+F1 to enter into virtual console,login with your username and password,then run the below commands on it,

```
sudo service lightdm restart
```

Comment: Sorry Avinash Raj.........I had tried it but it does not worked..

Comment: after applying the above command,login screen appear then login on it.

Comment: Yahh...Avinash i had login on it but its showing the same black screen as before......pls give me a solution

Comment: did you dualboot ubuntu and windows?

Comment: No i am using single OS(Ubuntu 13.10)......

Comment: did you already opened ubuntu 13.10?

Comment: I am already using it since 2 months ,but got strucked with this problem.....